# Transient property

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to add additional properties to my object, before I return it to the client. At they moment they are omitted from the object when it is serialized. Is there are way to add a transient property?

Answer (score 5):

I think setting type to `DataTypes.VIRTUAL` may help.

For example

```
var Line = sequelize.define("Line", {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
    },
    projects: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL
    }
});

Line.findAll().then(function (lines) {
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
        lines[i].projects = [];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(lines));
});
```

Output

```
[{"name":"test1","projects":[]},{"name":"test2","projects":[]}]
```

Documentation: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can make any changes to the returned object by first calling the serialization function that sequlize calls, which is the toJSON() method.

```
var jsonResult = result.toJSON();
jsonResult.newProperty = "New";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating an instance method should meet your needs: http://www.sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-expansion

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding an instance method, but it doesn't get serialized when it crosses the wire.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily add custom instance or class level methods.

```
            const User = sequelize.define('user', { firstname: Sequelize.STRING });

            // Adding a class level method
            User.classLevelMethod = function() {
              return 'foo';
            };

            // Adding an instance level method
            User.prototype.instanceLevelMethod = function() {
              return 'bar';
            };
```

Of course you can also access the instance's data and generate virtual getters:

```
            const User = sequelize.define('user', { firstname: Sequelize.STRING, lastname: Sequelize.STRING });

            User.prototype.getFullname = function() {
              return [this.firstname, this.lastname].join(' ');
            };

            // Example:
            User.build({ firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'bar' }).getFullname() // 'foo bar'
```